# Is it possible to retrieve an jQuery ajax response, then adding a print delay of data by iterating through an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Inside a typical ajax response you would simply just print out the data to a div.  I want to take the data response and split it up into an array, then iterate that array and add a random delay between appends.

In this specific example I am splitting up the response into each

tag. Then I am looking to add a delay before printing these responses.

So far this has not worked for me. It will only showcase the data response in full, even if I iterate through the array with setTimeout.

```
        //start the ajax
        $.ajax({
            //this is the php file that processes the data and send mail
            url: "/a_example.php?sim",  
            target:    '#crap',   // target element(s) to be updated with server response 
            //GET method is used
            type: "POST",

            //pass the data         
            data: data,     

            //Do not cache the page
            cache: false,

    success: function(data) {
                  var patt = /<p>(.*?)<\/p>/g;
                  var result = data.match(patt);
                var i;
                //alert(result.length);
                for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                    showResultMock(result[i]);

                }               


    },                  

    complete: function() {

        }

        });

function showResultMock(result){
 setTimeout(function(){  $('#modaldraftdetails .modal-body .draft-results').append(result); }, 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you iterate through the results, you basically create a pack of setTimeouts at the same time. Therefor those setTimeouts finish also at the same time.

Try a recursive solution, something like this:

```
/* Put this into the "success" callback */
var results = data.match(patt);
showResultMock(results, 0);

/* And this is your recursive fucntion's definition */
function showResultMock(results, i){
    if (i < results.length) {
        setTimeout(function(){  
            $('#modaldraftdetails .modal-body .draft-results').append(results[i]);
            showResultMock(results, ++i);
        }, 2000);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't fully understand why this works over what I had, but I can confirm that it does in fact work.  From what you are saying... before it would save the block of timeouts and execute them all at once ... and now it is executing each timeout as it occurs.

Comment: You got it @brant — your for loop executes in the span of a few milliseconds (depending on the size of the array of course). So effectively it says, "Do ten things...each of them in 2 seconds". The recursion is more like, "Do one thing in 2 seconds...do another thing in 2 seconds...etc."

Answer (score 2):

Try using recursion instead of iteration. Something like this:

```
const $resultsContainer = $('#results')
const results = [1,2,3]

function showResults(results) {
  if (!results.length) return
  setTimeout(function(){
    const result = results.shift()
    $resultsContainer.append(`<p>${result}</p>`)
    showResults(results)
  }, 2000)
}

showResults(results)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `function` recursively and use `Math.random()` to add a random delay like below:

```js
let ctn = $("#ctn"),
  results = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
  i = 0,
  maxDelay = 2000;

const printVal = val => {
  if (i < results.length) {
    //console.log(val);    
    ctn.append(`<span>${val}</span>`)
    setTimeout(() => {
      i++;
      printVal(results[i]);
    }, Math.random() * maxDelay)
  }
}

printVal(results[i])
```

```css
span{ margin: 5px; font-family: courier; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ctn"></div>
```